# Setting my paragraphs to begin at the top margin with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to build pdfs to digitize our reporting system at my company. I've used iTextSharp and so far it looks great but my margins don't seem to be working properly. I've set the margins to a config file and the left and right margins are working great, but my paragraph seems to start about 30% down the page regardless of the top and bottom margin. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public int PrintPdf()
    {
        //Getting the path
        //Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Test_Doc_Print") + ".pdf");
        object OutputFileName = this._path;

        //Making the PDF Doc
        iTextSharp.text.Document PDFReport = new iTextSharp.text.Document
        (
                PageSize.A4.Rotate(),
                /*this._left,
                this._right,
                this._top,
                this._bottom*/
                10,
                10,
                10,
                10
        );
        //Setting The Font
        string fontpath = @"C:\Windows\Fonts\";
        BaseFont monoFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "Consola.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font fontPDF = new Font(monoFont, this._fontSize);

        // create file stream for writing the PDF
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(this._path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        //FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\Reportlocation", FileMode.Create);

        // Create an FCFC scan object to convert TextToPrint page at a time
        FCFCScanner page = new FCFCScanner(this._text);

        // Create PDF writer and associate with file stream
        //iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFReport, fs);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFReport, fs);

        //Opening the PDF Doc
        PDFReport.Open();

        //Load each page from the string into the PDF
        page.NextPage();
        do
        {
            if (page.PageLength > 0)
            {
                Paragraph prg = new Paragraph(page.Page, fontPDF);
                PDFReport.Add(prg);
                PDFReport.NewPage();
                page.NextPage();
            }
        } while (page.MorePages);

        PDFReport.Close();
        return (0);
    }
```

I've set the margins to 10 (hardcoded for now) to show what I'm working with. This program should read a string that I send it from my StringBuider class. 
It's designed to receive one page of text at a time and to convert it into a PDF document.

Ok, so the problem: when the page is built, the first paragraph doesn't begin at the top margin. If I reduce the margin, it doesn't shift the paragraph up to the new margin. It's causing my PDFs to be much longer as the text that fits easily on a printer page takes two PDF pages. Any help with getting my paragraph to simply begin at the top margin would be really appreciated.

I'm relatively new to programming and this is my first post, so if you need more information, let me know and I'll add more info.

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using. The most recent version is no longer called iTextSharp, but iText for C#. The current version is 7.0.0.

Comment: Have you checked whether `page.Page` does not simply contain a number of line breaks at the start? Furthermore, if you ever happen to have a page with `page.PageLength == 0`, your `do .. while()` loop won't terminate.

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp, I'll check the new api.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea, thanks mkl!

It shouldn't have line breaks to start, when I run the program it actually prints a copy and makes a PDF copy. So the printed document seems like it's working great.